# Fastest way to get a vector of map keys sorted by map values?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `map<int int>`. I need to get a vector of the first int (the keys), but sorted in the second int's order (the value). What would be the fastest method to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyone who tells you they have the "fastest" way is a liar, since they don't know what hardware/C++ implementation etc you're using.

Here's one way:

```
typedef pair<int,int> item;

vector<item> mytmp(mymap.begin(), mymap.end());
sort(mytmp.begin(), mytmp.end(), [](item lhs, item rhs) { return lhs.second < rhs.second; });

vector<int> myvec;
myvec.reserve(mytmp.size());
transform(
    mytmp.begin(), mytmp.end(),
    back_inserter(myvec);
    [](item i) { return i.first; }
);
```

Comment: What is this: `[](item lhs, item rhs)`?

Comment: @baruch: it's a C++11 lambda expression. If your compiler doesn't implement them, you can write a functor to do the equivalent.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes lambda are not the best tool for teaching beginners with.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a second map in which you swap the `<key,value>` pairs to `<value,key>`. However, you will run into trouble if you have duplicate values.

What you might actually want is a bidirectional map. E.g., see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html .

Comment: That is no good since I *do* have duplicate values. I don't care what order they come up in.

Comment: you can create multimap for this

Comment: The problem you state can be resolved by using multimap. It is eaxactly the same as map but allows multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could put it into a `std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >` and then write a predicate to sort on the second value.  Then access the keys via the first value in the pair:

```
std::map<int, int>         the_map;
typedef std::pair<int,int> pair_type;

the_map[1] = 2;
the_map[2] = 1;
the_map[3] = 8;
the_map[4] = 8;
the_map[5] = 3;

struct Pred {
    bool operator()(pair_type const& a, pair_type const& b) const {
        return (a.second < b.second);
    }   
};  
struct Tran {
    int operator()(pair_type const& a) const {
        return a.first;
    }   
};  

std::vector<pair_type>     vec(the_map.begin(), the_map.end());
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Pred());

std::vector<int>           result;
transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(),  std::back_inserter(result), Tran());

BOOST_FOREACH(int const& r, result) {
    cout << r << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the +1.
Regarding the edit you made to transform into a vector of int - you can get the keys from the vector containing the pairs without the additional allocation.  At least there should be a result.reserve(vec.size());

Comment: well you'd want a resize not a reserve if you used result.begin().

Comment: Yep. You can pre-allocate with either resize() or reserve(). Note: If you use resize than change `back_inserter(result)` into `result.begin()` as you will be inserting into already created objects rather than using the back_inserter to insert into reserved space.